About recent events relating to a few users and moderators
Just to put some light on what's been happening lately...
I have been participating in the discussion a bit on this site, not because I'm active here but because I am active elsewhere and I have seen these patterns before. My goal here is just to get some explanations out there for why these VTCs seem to be happening to some people over others. TL;DR, the appearance of mod abuse is an artifact of posting rates.
I've done some analyses and digging over the past day or so, and have found a few things out. I know we're not supposed to pick out users by name but that's going to be pretty much impossible given the circumstances. I don't want to defame anyone/get anyone down; I genuinely am just trying to help everyone understand what's going on.
TL;DR
I want to make sure that everyone's perspectives are recognized here: a lot of close-votes were cast against a few users earlier, much more than other users receive, which makes the perception of mod abuse understandable. I also would like to point out that the number cast exactly matches how many one should expect, given that the users in question post ~30x more often than other users who have posted recently; there is no statistically-significant evidence of any mod abuse, and it seems like the recent VTCers have been doing their jobs perfectly-fine.
Analyzing user activity
First, see this answer in response to a "hey, my question wasn't a duplicate!" claim made by user80226 a few days ago:

...  I counted up the users who appear on the 50 most-recently-asked questions (since Dec 14). Obviously this isn't perfectly representative; it's only a 4-day sample and people get more or less active over time. At the same time, it's maybe useful to compare...

Those data were a little insufficient for me, so I went back and manually counted the latest 200 questions, which represents data almost a month back. The raw data are on a decently-large text file on my laptop, which I would be happy to share over some secure service; I wrote a Python script to tabulate all the data to see who was posting how much.
Here are the finalized and sorted data:



Name
Total Posts in the Last 200 (9:00 PM, 22 December 2024)




DJL
1


Frode Alfson Bjordal
1


Elvis
1


MMD
1


Jerra T
1


Maximilian
1



[... 55 more users who only posted once omitted for brevity ...]



Name
Posts




Mauro
1


Daniel
1


infatuated
1


Seramiti
1


8Mad0Manc8
1


Henry
2


Arthur Delannoy
2


Beng
2


Muhammad Luthfi Arkan Kamil
2


tenebris
2


Mohit
2


Ashish Shukla
2


Ian
3


dt128
3


Victor Bergman
3


Miss Understands
3


[Cyrillic]
3


Man of faith
4


User198
5


shindemo
5


Julius Hamilton
7


matrix
7


user80226
30


Syed
36



(There was a bug in the program that made one data point fail, which was a name that was incorrectly parsed that had 8 total posts in the last 200. I also omitted posts which had their associated accounts deleted, of which there were a couple. If you don't trust my data due to some bias, you are free to reproduce it yourself.)
In this group, 86 different users posted. Of the past 200 posts, essentially the entire month of December plus some, 66 (33% of the total posts and 76.7% of the total users) were posted by users who, in that entire time, had only posted once; i.e. 33% of all posts were contributed by 76.7% of the users who posted in that time. There are then 11 users who posted two or three times, which is more active but not much more active - another ~12.8% of the total users then contributed a grand total of 29 posts, which is 14.5% of the total posts. Five users contributed between 4 and 7 posts - 5.8% of the total users contributed 28 posts, 14% of the total. Notably among these is shindemo, who is only 7 days old on Philosophy SE; they have posted 5 times in 7 days, which should be noted to be on the high end of post frequencies.
Lastly, we see that user80226 and Syed between them posted 66 times in the last month or so; that makes 33% of all posts contributed in that timeframe having been contributed by 2.3% of the users who contributed.
Note regarding account ages
I restricted my data to the last 200 posts (~1 month) because I have other stuff to get done right now and don't have the time. It should be noted, though, that Syed has been around for 58 days, which is longer; the proportions for posts made by them/other very frequent posters will get larger as you approach that threshold, based on me skimming further past messages, and then will drop off once the Syed account creation date was passed. Same for user80226 and others.
Rough figures for those top two users: Syed has posted 127 times in their account's time of existence - averaging more than twice a day - and user80226 has posted 97 times in their 3 months of existence, mostly very recently, averaging around once a day. Additionally, in both cases, the great majority of posts are questions, not answers; do with that information what you will. Additionally note the exceptionally-low fraction of posts that these users have which have answers marked as accepted. I'm not going to specifically make any callouts about what this means - I, who have frequently asked in good faith, have often waited/procrastinated weeks or months or more before marking an answer as correct - but it is an additional piece of context that might be valuable here, as pointed out by Idiosyncratic Soul.
This is nothing to say about those users. I and the other high-reps and mods on other stacks have no issues with posting frequently - if you frequently post high-quality questions, great! The community should be grateful!
Analyzing the recent closures
I would like now to consider this answer that Causative wrote in response to another Meta discussion. I'm going to reiterate the comment I wrote on that post, and which I linked to elsewhere:

I have just tabulated the closed questions listed above to check for potential misuse. Of them (one was deleted, so I missed it), five were one-offs, Victor Bergman got two VTCs (not abnormally high for a new user), and Syed, shindemo, and user80226 (note that these are the serial-posters I mentioned earlier) comprised a whopping 14 of those votes. These are all new users (new users frequently misunderstand the site, not a huge issue if they're still learning) who also post very frequently compared to other users. This is not, as it turns out, statistically alarming...though I'm sure as the ones on the wrong end of the VTCs it can certainly feel that way. I haven't been active on Philosophy SE and won't pretend to know why there's been an uptick in serial posting; I'm trying to say, though, that this isn't a war where the mods are trying to go after whoever they want.

So here we see that of the 20 VTCs that were being complained about that Geo did, 70% were directed towards Syed, shindemo, and user80226. Keeping in mind what I said earlier about shindemo's post frequency despite not having been around for very long, note that those three users constitute 36.5% of the latest 200 posts on Philosophy SE.
Suppose that, upon being elected as moderator, I decided to hand out 39 random close votes during a period where these users were equally-active (that figure based on causative's comment on the statistics of Geo's recent closures). Given that 36.5% of the total posts were made by those three users, we should expect that around 36.5% of my random close votes will hit those three users. As math would have it (see link to Google calculator), 36.5% of the total 39 is 14.2 - lining up to within a small margin of error with the 14 close votes that those three users actually did get in the mass closure (at least, among the closed questions that I as a low-rep user can see, as seen on this answer).
The very important result here is that this "mod abuse" is not statistically distinguishable from the Geo and others just doing their regular jobs.
An aside for the aforementioned users who might be reading
Note that none of this implies that these users are worse at writing questions than any of the 80-something others that also posted. If my friend writes 10 posts in a month with a 10% closure rating, they will likely get around 1 closure in that month; if I write 100 posts in a month with the same 10% closure rating, i.e. roughly the same level of skill in writing questions, I will get 10 times as many closures, not because I'm any worse at writing questions, just because I wrote ten times more.
What does that tell us?
It turns out that the appearance of mod targeting is an artifact of the "targeted" users posting much more often than everyone else and thus getting proportionally-more close votes. What I have just shown - with cold hard data and simple mathematics - is that 14 close votes on those three users is not due to mod bias, since it is not meaningfully distinguishable from the mods choosing posts at random. What seems to have happened, from this analysis, is

Geo got around to going through recent posts to close off-topic/duplicate ones.
they found a few posts that were not suitable for the site;

Because Syed, user80226, and others post way, way, way more often than everyone else, the number of their posts that were to be closed was proportionally higher.


they closed those post with no particular thought put towards who was posting them (i.e. closing the post, not the user, as one should);
this resulted in a proportionate number of closures being allocated to those who posted the most, as one would intuitively expect.

For the users in question
This is not a fault on your part, and neither is it a fault on ours. Syed, user80226, and others have contributed a large number of questions to the site. That's a good thing! Now, in Syed's case, roughly half of all lifetime questions have been closed (I gathered this information with, again, manual checking), which means that you have room to grow, but the other half still exists! You have still contributed many good highly-upvoted questions to the site, with nine questions over +5 total and two +10s! For a user that young, that is in my experience not common. Same goes for user80226 and others.
What is the case is that you still have learning to do regarding what exactly is/isn't on topic here. On sites like Worldbuilding and Physics, that's not uncommon among new users - I have decent reps and close-vote privileges on both those sites, and I have found that a lot of the time it takes a few months to really get the hang of how to write a really good question (I still write VTCed questions to this day!), because it's hard, and you all still have not been on this Stack for long.
What is not the case, as I have shown with the statistical analysis performed heretofore, is that you are being targeted by mods for some reason. Yes, it is frustrating to get negative feedback on a post or have it closed or deleted. Yes, sometimes when one person is VTCing a lot (because they are especially active, or because they're a mod and it's their jobs), it can feel like you're being picked on. Almost a year ago when I joined SE I felt the exact same way. But the mods are trying to help you get the best answers by narrowing down what you can ask about to ensure that those others on the Stack can give you their best. As has been said many times across all Stack Exchange, including directly to Syed and probably to others through other channels,

Never take closure personally, because it is not easy to write a good question. Vagueness and ambiguity inhere to words. This site deals with a lot of technical detail. If your question isn't well formed, use it as an opportunity to figure out what you don't know. Every criticism is either off the mark, in which it can be ignored, or it is on the mark, in which case its an opportunity to learn and grow.

Emphasis JD's.
For everyone
What I also want to facilitate here is some respect throughout the community. Although I wasn't a part of the conversations, I am certain that these users in particular were antagonized at some point just because they felt the need to voice what they were feeling. For the record: I would feel the same way in their shoes, and I would likely have done some of the same things! Without having gone through a bunch of statistics like I just did, it seems exactly like there are a few active users being picked on by mods! If I were an active user on a Stack and woke up to find that a bunch of VTCs were just handed out, primarily to myself and a couple other active users, I'd be suspicious too. The users I've talked about here are not necessarily in the wrong, at least not completely.
Was everything that they did to react to that situation necessarily justified? Well, to them it must have been, at least to some extent. To me, and probably to Geo who was the subject of some of these reactions among others, it felt like an rude overreaction. But to them, it was likely all they could think to do in that situation.
There's been some similar stuff going on at Physics and Astronomy SE among others for a while. Some users have misconceptions, their posts are immediately closed (and, needlessly, heavily downvoted) because they phrased things a bit wrong, and then they don't feel like they have recourse to understand why the community reacted so quickly and, from some perspectives, so harshly. Then, they just repost again, or post frustratedly on Meta in vain, which results in the same reaction from the community. In the shorter cases of this happening, the user just quits, and SE has lost a potentially-valuable member of the community who could contribute a lot while that member is not coming back and is leaving with a bad taste in their mouth; in the longer cases (which are still in some instances ongoing), that user just ends up reposting and reposting and ban-evading, and instead of their valid-but-poorly-phrased questions ever actually getting answered, their posts are all deleted and accounts all banned, and SE becomes the censoring authoritarian community that is trying to suppress their knowledge/questions.
In extreme cases, that ends up leading them to believe that the scientific community as a whole, rather than just the few active SE members, is suppressing them. That leads down a whole new rabbit hole. I've seen my name posted on screenshots on Medium where the victims are calling out to the internet saying that we're suppressing them; my username and the usernames of others, who were just trying to help them get a question posted without being deleted, are now forever branded on some small corner of the Internet as the scientocratic elite suppressing the truth. In slightly-less-extreme cases you also get posts just dissing SE, saying it's just a few users who always upvote each other and downvote everyone else (a selection bias, given that many of the top questions on many Stacks are contributed by users who have only a few thousand rep and have long since left).
So: to (hopefully) finish all this off in one go, I want to say that the users in question here should take a step back and look at the numbers more closely, listen to the advice the community has given them (take a sec to learn what exactly is on topic, how to write really good questions, why some of your posts were closed), and I also want the community to know that these people were likely acting from a place of frustration with a system they don't quite understand when they are posting the way they are.
Mutual understanding is the way out. Watch any TV drama/horror and imagine what would happen if everyone just communicated clearly and completely for ten minutes.

I would add another statistic to your fine answer: The number of questions marked as answered and the percentage. A large number/percentage of questions left marked as unanswered can be an indicator that most of these questions are meant to generate discussion rather than answers. Also it indicates that the user is not sincere in the request for an answer to the posted question.

Thank you for that, Soul, I had acknowledged that earlier but didn't remember to add it in the post :)

Your efforts are well meant I'm sure. Do remember that it was top-4th user Kristian Berry's exit from the stack that moved the current state of the stack from uneasy-boil to open-wound

Also a note on conversations: You should tag ppl like so @IdiosyncraticSoul. Otherwise the person may not see; especially in the current phase where there are many main n meta threads going full blast

@MisterMiyagi That assumes those closures are kosher, not vindictive

"For a user that young...These are all new users" there have been several discussions about returning users with a new accounts. The commentary could be a bit more clear about person age versus account age versus total user presence via multiple accounts in this site.

Note: 34% of the last 200 questions are closed at the time of writing. That seems like a huge problem, regardless of whether one thinks those are appropriate closures or not.

@NotThatGuy A rare balanced view: "regardless of appropriate or not..." Here are some SEDE queries I tried to hack up. Unable to go the last mile (getting names of VTCers). Dunno whether it's my lack of SQL skills or it's just not possible at my privilege level...

Do you know about [data.se], that provides access to SE data via SQL? See also, e.g. queries for the number of questions per user for this month, and the percentage of closed questions per user (EDIT from my previous comment)

"is not statistically distinguishable from the Geo and others just doing their regular jobs." That doesn't follow. The closures being statistically similar to a random sample hopefully is not indicating the regular job of mods is to randomly close questions. Hopefully mods close questions based on content, and these statistics do not consider content. So the interpretation of these numbers is tricky. Under the questionable assumption that the high-frequency questions have a similar quality distribution as other questions, the closures did not target anyone. But that's an assumption.

Conversely, if these high-frequency questions all had perfect quality, then a closure of several of them would still indicate some targeting. Just because a random closure would close some does not justify closing questions that are the "best questions ever asked" on this site or anytime else in the history of philosophy. And the mod causative would testify that they all had to something with philosophy and thus were "perfectly fine".

@tkruse If you assume that the quality of all of the questions posted are roughly similar, then closures should be roughly random with some +/-. I made the assumption that the users in question make posts that are of average quality, so the random-dist interpretation is closer to reality. If you assume that Syed, 80226, etc. write worse than normal, you would expect more close votes allocated to them; not observing this, that would indicate that the mods would be biased in favor of those users, since they would be receiving disproportionately-little VTCs. That was my logic, at least.

This analysis does not address recent complaints. The complaint is that questions that don’t actually break the VTC rules posed by me/user80226/etc seem to be closed at a higher rate than others. You cannot put those questions in the same bucket as questions asked by new users which may warrant more obvious closure and then judge how often those questions are closed. You must perform semantic analysis and this doesn’t do any of that. Lastly, how often questions have accepted answers (which is an important but different discussion) has nothing to do with whether a question should be closed

My primary point was that you and user80266 posted around 30x more than everyone else. It should be expected, then, that you receive more incorrect closures, given that the imperfect system will be acting on you guys 30x more than other users. Incorrect closures also happen to other users, at what I'm guessing is a very similar rate, but if it's once a year for them, it would be perfectly-reasonable for it to happen to use once every few weeks. The tendency I have noticed on other sites is that more frequent questions tend to be lower-quality questions as well (I can bring up examples from...

...WBSE, Physics SE, and a couple others), and this also correlates with questions not getting an accepted answer; all of that is going to make it more likely for you to get post closures, which of course increases the likelihood that one of them will be wrong. The whole point of me doing these hours of analysis was to show that there isn't actually any evidence of anything that can't be explained by "you are the most active users by far in the last few months".

Excellent data driven analysis!

Beautifully done. Thank you. If there was any way I could award a bounty to this question and to transfer some of my XP to you, I would gladly do so; you deserve a heck of a lot more than a mere up-vote.

If you want to know if Syed and user80226 have been closed at a rate above average, we can do better than your analysis. I ran this query to find recent questions (since Nov 1) by username and closed status. Then I downloaded the csv and ran a python script to sort by the ratio of closed posts to total posts for each user.
For all users excluding Syed and user80226, 27.8% (88/316) of questions were closed. 39.5% of user80226's questions (19/48) were closed, and 50% of Syed's questions (36/72) were closed. So that's significantly above average.
The other consideration is that what matters is not just how often these users' questions are closed, but how often they are closed in comparison to questions by other users of similar quality. This is a subjective matter difficult to analyze with statistics. But speaking subjectively, many of the non-Syed, non-user80226 questions are low-quality posts by new users, or by certain established users with a very "nonstandard" thought process. Whereas, frankly, Syed's questions generally do make sense and often reference philosophical works. user80226 also generally makes sense. (Not to say I agree with them; usually I disagree with them both. I think every time I've answered a Syed question it's been to tell him he's wrong. Nonetheless, I can see where he's coming from.)
We do have one very clear example of an absolutely on topic question - of the type 2 question form "What does philosophical school of thought Y say about X?" - being closed. I'd consider that a smoking gun.
Now why are these questions of adequate quality being closed? In the case of Syed, we don't have to guess; some users on meta have explained why they have been voting to close. They've said he's just posting too much; they've said they don't like that many of his questions are about God; they don't like that he is rude in comments; and they have (falsely, as far as I know) accused him of being a different banned user. None of those are legitimate reasons to close a question.
RE Geoffrey - his recent action seems to be that he just closed most questions with any outstanding close votes. That's not targeted at any user.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
